# Error: Segment fault

Tags: c++

Me aparece un error: segmentation fault SIGSEGV ... el error está comentado en el código.
al parecer el error está en la función *insetarLista* ya que al momento de entrar en ella, el programa se "pierde”

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo1{
    int dato;
    Nodo1 *siguiente;
};

void insertarLista(Nodo1 *&, int);
void menu();

int main(){
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    Nodo1 *lista = NULL;
    int opcion, dato;

    do{
        cout << "1. Insertar elementos a la lista"<<endl;
        cout << "2. Mostrar elementos de la lista"<<endl;
        cout << "3. Salir"<<endl;
        cout << "Opcion: ";
        cin >> opcion;

        switch (opcion){
            case 1: cout << "Digite el numero a aniadir: ";
                    cin >> dato;
                    insertarLista(lista,dato);
                    break;
            case 2: cout << "Los elementos son: ";
                    mostrarLista(lista);
                    break;
        }   
    }while(opcion!=3);
}

void insertarLista (Nodo1 *&lista, int n){
    Nodo1 *nuevo_nodo1 = new Nodo1();
    nuevo_nodo1->dato = n;

    Nodo1 *aux1 = lista;
    Nodo1 *aux2;

    while ((aux1 != NULL) && (aux1->dato < n)){
        aux2 = aux1;
        aux1 = aux1->siguiente;
    }

    if (lista = aux1){
        lista = nuevo_nodo1;
    }else{
        aux2->siguiente = nuevo_nodo1;//aqui el error
    }
    nuevo_nodo1->siguiente = aux1;
}
```

Comment: No escribas por favor contenido que no va a ser relevante como ese enorme cartel de ayuda

Comment: @Aprendiz disculpa. Es que no me dejaban formular la pregunta...

Comment: Aquí `if (lista = aux1)` estás haciendo una asignación, no una comparación, con lo que la primera vez que entra en la función, va directo al else, y como aux2 no está inicializado te da una excepción. Nos faltan datos de cómo quieres insertarlos, de mayor a menor o de menor a mayor. Trata de depurar el código paso a paso para entender lo que hace y averiguar cómo hacerlo para que se comporte como tú quieres. Y otra cosa: al crear los nodos, y en general todos los punteros, inicialízalos a NULL, para indicar el final de la lista cuando lo insertes.

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema está en `if (lista = aux1)`.

Estás haciendo una asignación en lugar de una comparación (`==`).

La primera vez que agregas un nodo, `lista` es null, asignas ese null a `aux1` y en el `if` asignas otra vez null a `lista`.

El resultado de una asignación en un `if` es el valor final de la variable asignada: `lista`, que vale null o 0, lo cual equivale a `false`, entonces entra al `else` donde tratas de llamar `aux2->siguiente`, pero `aux2` en este momento también es null porque nunca entró al `while` porque `aux1` era null. Y así obtienes el segmentation fault.

Y como consejo, trata de usar `nullptr` en lugar de NULL, y también incluir `<string>`, no `<string.h>`, si vas a hacer algo con strings.